# Converting series of numbers from a string, into different numbers

Tags: java, string, function

Pretty much what I need to happen, is I need to take a string

Example

```
 String ln = "It's so pretty! &#55357;";
```

The idea, is we're taking this string, a converting the end of the line..

```
&#55357;
```

into

```
&#127037;
```

I can convert that easy enough, but the problem there can be multiple numbers to change. The string could be...

```
 String ln = "It's so pretty! &#55357;&#56357; But &#55468; &#55357;";
```

And I need to convert, every number in that line..

The purpose of this, is each one of those codes, is unicode for a character, but it's shorthanded, and not correct for the purpose that I need it to be.

- Every number is in the same format.. and will always be 5 characters long.
- Every code, starts with "&#" and ends with a semicolon.
- Every code, can be anywhere in the string

When I tried to create a method to convert the numbers, I pretty much split the string on "&#" and it works, for every case, except for when they aren't connected in series. For example,

```
String ln = "Gahh it's so pretty. &#55357;&#56845;&#55357;&#56845;&#55357;&#56874;";
```

It will solve that string, and convert all the numbers, and can recreate the string as it was originally, just with modified numbers. But it wouldn't recreate a string, with a gap in between number codes.

---

This is the code I have used.. like I said, it converts like its supposed to, just only in one case, and I haven't figured out how to make it work on all cases.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String ln = "Gahh it's so pretty. &#55357;&#56845;&#55357;&#56845;&#55357;&#56874;";
    //71680 + code present
    //Gahh it's so pretty. &#55357;&#56845;&#55357;&#56845;&#55357;&#56874;
    String tmp = ln;
    String[] codes = tmp.split("&#");
    System.out.println(ln);
    ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
        codes[i] = codes[i].trim();
        if (codes[i].length() != 6)
            continue;
        if (codes[i].endsWith(";")) {
            codes[i] = codes[i].substring(0, codes[i].length()-1);
        }
        try {
            ids.add(Integer.parseInt(codes[i]) + 71680);

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("Error in conversion: " + codes[i]);
        }
    }
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(codes));

    codes = tmp.split("&#\\d{5}");
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(codes));
    for (int i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
        //System.out.println(codes[i]);
        if (codes[i].equals(";")) {
            codes[i] = "&#"+ids.remove(0)+";";

        }
    }
    for (String s : codes)
        System.out.print(s);
    System.out.println();

}
```

I just need some input on this. If you're willing to correct a few things, I'd gladly accept the help, but honestly, I'm more interested in how you would approach this problem.

Comment: `split()` is the wrong tool for this job.  Basically, set up a `Matcher`, as in dkatzel's answer.  The `find()` method of `Matcher` can be used to look for successive matches, one by one.  `split()` is most useful when your strng is a sequence of "fields" separated by delimiters.  But trying to look at your input string this way doesn't work; `"56357; But "` can't be considered a "field" or any other cohesive unit in your source string.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("&#(\\d+);");
```

should work to find all the numbers in your string.  The [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) objects also have methods `start()` and `end()` to get the offsets of the matches so you can use those to make substrings to help build up your new String

Answer (score 1):

You can use the look ahead/behind regex: `"(?<=&#)(\\d+)(?=;)"` to match and replace.

```
    String ln = "Gahh it's so pretty. &#55357;&#56845;&#55357;&#56845;&#55357;&#56874;";

    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("(?<=&#)(\\d+)(?=;)");
    Matcher mat = patt.matcher(ln);
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    while(mat.find()) {
      mat.appendReplacement(buf, Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(mat.group(1)) + 71680));
    }
    mat.appendTail(buf);

    System.out.println(buf.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

With `Regex`, using `Matcher` and `Pattern` you can construct a pattern as so:

```
"&#(\\d{5});\\s?"
```

This will match your codes that may or may not be followed by a space.  The numbers of the code are captured into group 1 which you can apply your modifications to.  Then replace each code with the new code like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList() {{
        add("It's so pretty! &#55357;");
        add("Gahh it's so pretty. &#55357;&#56845;&#55357;&#56845;&#55357;&#56874;");
        add("It's so pretty! &#55357;&#56357; But &#55468; &#55357;");
    }};

    for (String ln : lines) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("&#(\\d{5});\\s?").matcher(ln);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)) + 71680;
            ln = ln.replace(matcher.group(0), "&#" + number + "; ");
        }
        System.out.println(ln);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
It's so pretty! &#127037; 
Gahh it's so pretty. &#127037; &#128525; &#127037; &#128525; &#127037; &#128554; 
It's so pretty! &#127037; &#128037; But &#127148; &#127037;
```

As you can see, spaces are added after each code.